# Меняется значение при записи в список python

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, lxml

Спарсил данные с Яндекса, с помощью BeautifulSoup4 получил элементы
При записи чисел 2498, 2129, 1646, 1208 в список, строки меняются на такие значения:
'''
['2\u2009498', '2\u2009129', '1\u2009646', '1\u2009208']
'''
Но через 'print()' выводятся обычные числа типа 'str', что с этим можно сделать?
Код:

```
def read_index():
    metrics = []
    with open(r'index.html', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        src = file.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
    for dataid in all_id.values():
        try:
            element = soup.find('tr', {'data-id': f'{dataid}'}).find(
                class_='conversion-report__goal-metric-row_type_visits').find('td',
                                                                              class_='conversion-report__goal-metric-row-right')
            # metrics[key] = element.text
            metrics.append(element.text)
            print(element.text)
        except Exception:
            title = soup.find('tr', {'data-id': f'{dataid}'}).find(class_='conversion-report__goal-title')
            # metrics[key] = ''
            print(f'Ошибка в {title.text}')
    print(metrics)
```

Comment: Код не похож на валидный: `metrics.append(element.)`

Comment: Там 'elements.text', в исходном коде этой ошибки нет, не обращайте внимание, это опечатка при написании вопроса:(

Comment: @RomanKonoval как это декодировать при записи в список?

Answer (score 1):

[\u2009](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2009) - это юникод codepoint для короткого пробела. Очевидно, в числах такое форматирование - тысячи отделяются коротким пробелом.

Убрать все пробелы из строки можно так:

```
x = '2\u2009498'
import re
x = re.sub('\s', '', x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Они не меняются, они уже с тем символом, просто он выглядит как пробел `'1 208'`.

[\u2009 - это THIN SPACE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2009/index.htm)

Этот символ использовался там как пробел, т.к. обычные пробелы в HTML могут быть игнорированы.

Когда вы выводили список, то строки там показывались строковыми представлениями (как если бы их через `repr` выводили):

```
s = '1 208'
print(s)
print(repr(s))
# 1 208
# '1\u2009208'
```

Вам нужно убрать ненужные символы, например:

```
s = '1 208'
s = ''.join(c for c in s if c in '0123456789')
print(s)
print(repr(s))
# 1208
# '1208'
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло:)

Comment: @Maksik, пожалуйста :) И не забудьте проголосовать за ответы, что вам помогли :)